# Lifting a homomorphism between modules in exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $0\to A\to P\to B\to 0$ and $0\to C\to Q \to D\to 0$ be two exact sequences of $R$ modules, with $Q$ injective, $\operatorname{Hom}(B,D)=0$, and let there be a homomorphism $\alpha:A\to C$. I'm trying to show that $\alpha$ lifts to a homomorphism $a^*:P\to C$.

The only way I can see of making use of the injectivity of $Q$ is by applying the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\cdot,Q)$ to both sequences, and examining the resulting exact sequences. From here however, I cannot see how to use the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}(B,D)=0$. I was thinking of using the *five lemma*, but do not seem to be in the possession of enough mono- and epi- morphisms. Any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need $\hom(B,D)=0$ to just get a lift of $\alpha$. Just use the universal property of injective modules.

Comment: @user45765 Ah, my mistake. I misread the problem as lifting from $P$ to $Q$! Of course snake lemma is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>\alpha>> P @>\beta>> B @>>> 0 \\
@. @VfVV \\
0 @>>> C @>\gamma>> Q @>\delta>> D @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
Since $Q$ is injective, there exists $g\colon P\to Q$ such that $g\alpha=\gamma f$:
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>\alpha>> P @>\beta>> B @>>> 0 \\
@. @VfVV @VgVV \\
0 @>>> C @>\gamma>> Q @>\delta>> D @>>> 0
\end{CD}
Now $\delta g\alpha=\delta\gamma f=0$, so there exists $h\colon B\to D$ such that $h\beta=\delta g$ (homomorphism theorem):
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>\alpha>> P @>\beta>> B @>>> 0 \\
@. @VfVV @VgVV @VhVV \\
0 @>>> C @>\gamma>> Q @>\delta>> D @>>> 0
\end{CD}
By assumption, $h=0$, so also $\delta g=0$, which implies the image of $g$ is contained in the kernel of $\delta$, which is the same as the image of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What homomorphism theorem do you refer to? I googled it, but it doesn't seem to be a common theorem.

Comment: @K.Power A homomorphism $f\colon M\to N$ factors through the quotient $M/L$ if and only if $L\subseteq \ker f$.

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed a very common theorem, first chapter of the book I'm using, but does not seem to have a universally agreed upon name.